# why does read xml file and return json returns empty json object

Tags: node.js, json

I try to read a xml file lie this and return Json when access a endpoint, but I get empty json as result meaning the xml file has not been read. I think it might have something to do with synchron and asynchronous, but not sure how to solve it. Can someone please help out?

```
 function ReadXmlAndReturnJson(xmlFile) {
  const fs = require("fs");
  var parser = require('xml2json');
  var json = parser.toJson('');

  let xmlFileName = __dirname + "/data/" + xmlFile;

  fs.readFile(xmlFileName, 'utf8', function(err, data) {
      var json = parser.toJson(data);
      //console.log("to json ->", json);
   }); 
   return json;
}

server.get("/api/standings/:teamId", (request, response) => {
  const { teamId } = request.params
  let standings = ReadXmlAndReturnJson(fileName);
  console.log(standings);
  response.json(standings);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`readFile` is a async function, have some way to deal with that function. Basically, use callback style.

Make `ReadXmlAndReturnJson` become a callback function like `readFile`

```
 function ReadXmlAndReturnJson(xmlFile, callback) { // callback param
  const fs = require("fs");
  var parser = require('xml2json');
  var json = parser.toJson('');

  let xmlFileName = __dirname + "/data/" + xmlFile;

  fs.readFile(xmlFileName, 'utf8', function(err, data) {
      if (err) {
          return callback(err); // return with error
      }
      var json = parser.toJson(data);
      callback(null, json); // return json
   });
}

server.get("/api/standings/:teamId", (request, response) => {
  const { teamId } = request.params
  // where is fileName come from?
  ReadXmlAndReturnJson(fileName, function (err, data) { // do the same as you do for `readFile` function
     if (err) {
         return response.status(500).send(err); // something went wrong
     }
     response.json(data);
  });
  
});
```